# Problems with while condition or condition loop (beginner)

Tags: python, while-loop

im having some trouble understanding why my while/or loop doesn't cut out once the second condition is met

```
## Guess the word game
import random
secret_word = "computer"
guess = ""
vclueinput, vclueletter , vcluepos = "", "", ""
vtries, vlimit = 0, 5
while guess != secret_word or vlimit > 0: ## I've also tried with vlimit != 0 and fliping the condition's order
    print("You have " + str(vlimit) + " guesses left")
    guess = input("Guess the word: ")
    if guess != secret_word and vlimit > 0:
        vtries += 1
        vlimit -= 1
        vclueinput = input("Wrong! Do you want a clue? [Y/N]: ")
        if vclueinput == "Y" or vclueinput == "y":
            vcluepos = random.randint(0, int(len(secret_word)))
            vclueletter = secret_word[vcluepos]
            print((vcluepos) * "_" + vclueletter + ((int(len(secret_word))) - vcluepos - 1) * "_")
            print("")
        elif vclueinput == "N" or vclueinput == "n":
            print("")
        else:
            print("error")
            print("")
    elif guess == secret_word:
        print("Correct! The secret word is: " + secret_word )
        print("It took you " + str(vtries) + " guesses")
    elif vlimit <= 0:
        print("You are out of Guesses")
```

As you can see i have a down counter (vlimit) that sould brake the while loop as soon as it hits 0, for some reason the loop breaks when `guess = secret_word` but not when `vlimit = 0` it just goes

```
print("You have " + str(vlimit) + " guesses left") ##vlimit being 0
guess = input("Guess the word: ")
print("You are out of Guesses")
```

I hope you are able to help me out

Answer (score 1):

If you use `or`, only one of the condition needs to be true for the loop to continue.
If you want to break the loop if one condition gets false, use `and`. Like
`while guess != secret_word and vlimit > 0:`

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer! in this case I want the loop to break if either the conditions are met, not both, in this case the loop only breaks when the first condition is met but if the second condition is met the loop doesn't break

Comment: This approach does exactly what you're asking. If either condition becomes true, the loop breaks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can add two `break` statements in your codes so that you can break the loop if user guesses correct or when his tries reaches the limit he exits.

```
## Guess the word game
import random
secret_word = "computer"
guess = ""
vclueinput, vclueletter , vcluepos = "", "", ""
vtries, vlimit = 0, 5
while guess != secret_word or vlimit > 0: ## I've also tried with vlimit != 0 and fliping the condition's order
    print("You have " + str(vlimit) + " guesses left")
    guess = input("Guess the word: ")
    if guess != secret_word and vlimit > 0:
        vtries += 1
        vlimit -= 1
        vclueinput = input("Wrong! Do you want a clue? [Y/N]: ")
        if vclueinput == "Y" or vclueinput == "y":
            vcluepos = random.randint(0, int(len(secret_word)))
            vclueletter = secret_word[vcluepos]
            print((vcluepos) * "_" + vclueletter + ((int(len(secret_word))) - vcluepos - 1) * "_")
            print("")
        elif vclueinput == "N" or vclueinput == "n":
            print("")
        else:
            print("error")
            print("")
    elif guess == secret_word:
        print("Correct! The secret word is: " + secret_word )
        print("It took you " + str(vtries) + " guesses")
        break
    elif vlimit <= 0:
        print("You are out of Guesses")
        break
```

The two `break` statements are in the last two `elif` statements.

I hope you enjoy it. Have Fun :)

Comment: Thank you very much!, ill research ```break``` statements to know when and how to use them.